# Conflicting Java installations Eclipse/Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, version

I'm trying to install a java extension as a jar file. When I have just Oracle Java version 8 installed, I can run the jar-file.

However, when I download Eclipse, it includes openjkd7 and somehow this messes up my Java installation. When I include the jar file and try to run, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:<path>    Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

What is going on? Is Eclipse using a different version of Java? How can this be resolved?

Comment: What OS?  Windows?  Linux?  Also, open a Command Prompt or terminal and type java -version and post the output of the command.  Then run the command echo %JAVA_HOME% (Windows), echo $JAVA_HOME (Linux)

Comment: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 64.

java -version yields:
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)

The echo $JAVA_HOME doesn't return anything at all for me.

Comment: I guess I'd like to know how to tell my system or IDE which version of JAVA to use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do the following things :

a.) Set the JAVA_HOME, probably should be the 1.8 version.  Quit all instances of Eclipse.
b.) Re-open Eclipse.  Then, In Eclipse, configure the Eclipse project Build Path to the 1.8...it SHOULD be the default JRE/JDK in Eclipse now, but it's hard to say since your installed Eclipse with a bundled JRE/JDK.

Right-click on the Eclipse project.
Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries (Tab) > Choose the JDK you want.

You can also configure Alternate versions of JRE/JDK from the screen...

Comment: This did it. Thanks so much!